# What is the "purpose" of commas in intel syntax?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, language-design, intel-syntax

I've been writing a programming game -- and with that comes writing a programming language. Initially I wanted the programming language to be a gross simplification of assembly language (like the game EXAPUNKS if anybody knows what that is).

But as things went on, I got pretty feature addicted and the language ended up pretty much exactly like a slightly simplified x86 with intel syntax. With one key distinction:

My language doesn't require commas. `mov [eax+1] ebx` is perfectly valid in my game.

So, why are commas needed in the intel syntax? Is there some case where a lack of commas would cause ambiguity? I am considering implementing commas just to make the language more familiar but it doesn't really need them.

Comment: Some people like to leave space between operators, e.g. `[eax + 1]` for readability. You can probably still parse that, though.

Comment: In Intel syntax, you can write `eax[ebx]` for a memory operand.  Without commas, this is ambiguous.

Comment: intel is not a syntax.  Assembly language is defined by the assembler, not the target.  You can choose whatever syntax you want, commas or not, no reason to mimic something else for example ld [eax + 1] ebx is perfectly fine and understandable.  As the author of the syntax you define if there is a case where you cant distinguish something without more symbols.

Comment: @old_timer If not syntax, then what do you call the things that Intel assembly and AT&T assembly are?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I would call both categories *Intel* and *AT&T* either **philosophy** or **paradigma**.  Assemblers based on *Intel paradigma* define field order as 
`instruction destination, source ,second_source`, and assemblers based on *AT&T paradigma* use `instruction source, destination`.

Comment: @old_timer: "Intel syntax" means the dialect of x86 asm syntax defined by the Intel corporation and used in their manuals.  *Not* "asm for Intel-architecture / IA32" (which would not be a useful term if that's what it actually meant and had just been invented by the OP). Stack Overflow even has a tag for it (with a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info)), and the OP used that tag.  Of course there are multiple flavours of Intel syntax between NASM-style vs. MASM-style, but all of them require commas to separate operands.

Comment: @fuz Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for! So the commas are there to distinguish `eax[ebx]` from `'eax [ebx]` which could be hard to spot or something?

Comment: @ThorCorreia among other things, yes.  If you use a parser generator like yacc to build your assembler, you'll find that it's very hard to build unambiguous grammars without some separator between operands.

Comment: That's just the thing, I didn't find it difficult at all. But most likely I'm leaving out parts of the intel syntax that would cause ambiguity.

Comment: @ThorCorreia it gets rather hard once expressions are involved (e.g. `foo-10` vs. `foo,-10`).

Comment: I see — is it typical to elide the spaces?