# error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix

Tags: assembly, x86, clang, inline-assembly

[image]

When I use Mac to compile the intel inline assembly, it gives me error. Some one can help me?

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    unsigned int x,y;
     x=42;
     y=24;

     asm volatile("add %0 %1": "=r"(x) :"r" (y) : "cc");
    printf("Hello world\n",x);
}

Comment: 1: Post code as text, not images. 2: Add the compiler output. `I get an error` is _not enough information_, we actually do need to _see_ the error message to understand the problem.

Comment: Judging from the error, clang doesn't seem to support `-masm=intel`? It substituted `%eax` for example.

Comment: You're missing a comma between the operands.

Comment: @Jester: Only very recent clang acts like GCC in having `-masm=intel` handle `asm()` statements as Intel syntax.  [Can I use Intel syntax of x86 assembly with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347909) says clang 14 and later.

Comment: [What is the "purpose" of commas in intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62101792) is only answered in comments, but it's why x86 asm needs commas between operands.